# Why google firebase not clarifying that firebase no more supporting cordova?

Tags: cordova, firebase, google-oauth, visual-studio-cordova, inappbrowser

Why Google firebase not clarifying that firebase no more supporting Cordova?

Officially they have said OAuth will not be supported from inAppBrowser but they are still maintaining the article- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

When I spoke to one of the support members they also said it's working my project has some issues.
But the truth is when I am running with Old API Level like 19 /platform 4.4.2 its working -not able to show the working image as more than 2 links not supported.

but when running with new API level 24/platform 7.0 it's not working and showing "disallowed user agent"
[API24-firebase-not-working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNdCw.jpg)

Can anyone clarify why it's not working with newer versions?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth supports OAuth sign-in for Cordova apps. As you mentioned, the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova supports that. It should work for all modern Android and iOS versions.
However, it doesn't actually work with inAppBrowser plugin the way the legacy Firebase Auth SDK did. inAppBrowser is used only as a fallback for certain cases (old iOS versions). It will use browsertab plugin to open the app in a Chrome custom tab (system browser when chrome not installed) or SFSafariViewController. The instructions explain that.
What you are experiencing "disallowed user agent" is only specific to Google sign-in using an embedded webview. That is now blocked due to the insecurity of embedded webviews. Firebase Auth uses the recommendeded Chrome custom tab (system browser when chrome not installed) or SFSafariViewController instead. Check this post for more details on this specific issue (Google sign-in being blocked in embedded webviews): https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

Comment: Thanks for responding but the issue not replicable with older platform and API level which is adding to the confusion as firebase article says it's supported and it working in some versions but not with all the Android versions. Btw the link do not provide a working example/ sample of how to use native chrome browser tab with firebase & hybrid app like cordova, can you please provide the same?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean older platform and API level. What Firebase article are you talking about? I can tell you Firebase Auth works for all modern Android version. I personally have tested with Android 4.x and Firebase OAuth works.

Comment: I added a screen shot which is showing that it's not working with API level 24/platform 7.0 same code is working with platform 4.4.2/ API level 19

Comment: Unfortunately I was not allowed to put more than one link so I was not able to show the working versions

Comment: The link I am talking about already in the main post here it is again https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova I follow this and made it work with 4.x as you are saying but it's not working with 7.0 not sure about other versions

Comment: What error are you getting with 7.0? "disallowed user agent"? When you trigger the flow, does it open a chrome custom tab in that device?

Comment: The screenshot shows that it's opening with webview but with the older 4.x versions same code is working not sure how I can share the same screenshot which is working

Comment: ok I Have tested with all other versions other than recent 8.0.0 its working with each one of them only 7.0 its not working. It my bad luck I started with 7.0 for testing and that's the one not working!!
I am not sure if I should be apologize by making the comments firebase not supporting cordova. but its nowt working with 7.0 its working with 7.1.1 not a single line of code changed.